# How to get previously changed records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

How to get previously changed records for particular data?
From the below records, I have tried but didn't got idea to make it

```
DECLARE @l_MSISDN AS TABLE 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Old NVARCHAR(50),
    New NVARCHAR(50),
    AuthDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @l_MSISDN VALUES
    ('A','B',GETDATE()),
    ('B','C',GETDATE()),
    ('C','D',GETDATE()),
    ('R','T',GETDATE()),
    ('R','Q',GETDATE())

;WITH CTE AS
(
    select  New,OLD,AuthDate 
    from    @l_MSISDN nolock
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * from cte 
    where New = OLD
)

select * from cte
order by AuthDate
```

```
Old             New              AuthDate
A               B               2018-04-04 11:06:51.953
B               C               2018-04-04 10:39:03.563
C               D               2014-12-20 06:25:20.397
R               T               2016-02-10 15:25:20.123
Q               R               2015-09-21 15:25:20.330
```

I expect output as

```
old               new             Authdate
A                 B               2014-12-20 06:25:20.397
B                 C               2015-09-21 15:25:20.330
C                 D               2016-02-10 15:25:20.123
```

I'll give input as D

Comment: Shorter values make sample data much easier to read. E.g. 1, 2 and 3, instead of 5548933000218, 5548923000218 and 5548933000318.

Comment: Why do you expect *those* records? How do you decide that one of those is `old` and another `new`?

Comment: Thanks for telling us what you expect of us. We *expect* to see your attempts first though; what have you tried, why didn't it work?

Comment: Also, on a different note, SQL Server 2008 (and 2008R2) has about 3 weeks left of support; i strongly recommend that you start getting your upgrade process started very very soon.

Comment: The data shows a parent-child relation, not old/new. The query you posted returns a hierarchy. BTW `NOLOCK` means `read dirty data while taking excessive locks`. It doesn't make things go faster.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's not a hierarchy like record, am swapping a value from one to another

Comment: Wait, where are those dates coming from in your expected output? They are nothing like what they were in the sample data.

Comment: Out of nine answered questions you have marked only three as answered.Before you ask your next question, please go through your old questions and mark correct answers.

Answer (score 2):

You weren't too far off with your attempt. You need to reference your original table in the `UNION ALL` as well by a `JOIN`:

```
DECLARE @Start char(1) = 'D';

SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM (VALUES ('A', 'B', CONVERT(datetime,'2018-04-04T11:06:51.953')),
             ('B', 'C', CONVERT(datetime,'2018-04-04T10:39:03.563')),
             ('C', 'D', CONVERT(datetime,'2014-12-20T06:25:20.397')),
             ('R', 'T', CONVERT(datetime,'2016-02-10T15:25:20.123')),
             ('Q', 'R', CONVERT(datetime,'2015-09-21T15:25:20.330'))) V (Old, New, AuthDate);

WITH rCTe AS(
    SELECT T.Old,
           T.New,
           T.AuthDate
    FROM #Temp T
    WHERE T.New = @Start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.Old,
           T.New,
           T.AuthDate
    FROM #Temp T
         JOIN rCTE r ON r.Old = T.New)
SELECT r.Old,
       r.New,
       r.AuthDate
FROM rCTe r;

DROP TABLE #Temp;
```

Comment: You're welcome @Shahul. Please do mark the answer as the solution if it fixed the problem, so that future readers with the same question know the answer was helpful. Thanks.